# Tax is not showing accurately

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have added one product with 12% Tax as 1250

But when I check in cart it is showing Tax as 133.93 but it should show 150

Please check the below screenshot for more information.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Your help will be appreciated.

[image: 3]

Tax Setting Please find the attached image
[image]

Comment: Have you checked your backend 
133.93 is 10.71 % of 1250

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your tax configurations in the backend

Comment: Dominic Xigen For Tax settings please find the attached image.